# Oracle Geospatial SQL Error [13199] [72000]: ORA-13199: wk buffer merge failure

Tags: oracle, geospatial, oracle-spatial

im using `MDSYS.SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(GEOMETRY)`, and i get this constant error sometimes during the day

Query execution failed

`Razón:`
`SQL Error [13199] [72000]: ORA-13199: wk buffer merge failure`
`ORA-06512: en "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", línea 857`
`ORA-06512: en "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", línea 896`

after using those geospatial funtions, any query using some of those keeps failing all the time until i restart the instance

Some get this error?
im using this version
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production

Thanks

Has anyone been able to resolve this error?

Comment: https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2831076_1.html

Answer (score 0):

See the comment added by astentx. If no patch is available for your Oracle DB version, you can request it via MyOracleSupport.

Comment: already try, but its a common bug working with spatial data according to oracle forum, instead using wkt, now im using geojson, and works better for my needs

Comment: Great, you have found a suitable workaround.